# When fsck the `/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_web`, there comes error status: { DRDY ERR } error: { UNC }

Tags: centos, fsck

When I fsck the `/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_web`, there comes a issue:

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_web contains a file system with errors, check forced.  
exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x3 SErr 0x0 action 0x8
```

[image]

You see, there over and over again shows the `status: { DRDY ERR }  error: { UNC }.` issues, why I get this issue?  how to fix it? let the fsck on the rails?

---

**EDIT**

My CentOS 6.5 server startup, there come bellow error:

[image]

So, I use the `fsck -y /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_web` to fix it, but it reports the upper error.

---

**EDIT-2**

I find a similar post there:
https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1034762.html

And the hobong says:

```
It's Kernel Bug on ata ACPI. I put "options libata noacpi=1" on /etc/modprobe.d/options and the ERROR is gone.
```

I want to do like him, but I find I can not open it:

[image]

Comment: and what is your question about it?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens See my EIDT.

Comment: Your edit helps  a bit, but still you didn't ask/include a question, something that ends with a "?". So please add an explicit question.

Comment: Can you post the line that you enter and gives the E303 error